# Steps to restore MarkLogic database from backup

Tags: marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic Database restore process. I have a backup available with me taken from production. I am trying to restore it on DIT. All the Forest and configuration is same for both the environments/servers. Please let me know the steps to restore MarkLogic database using backup. My MarkLogic version is '8.0-6.7'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongly recommend reading the documentation. Chapter 20 of the Admin Guide deals with this precisely.

http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/admin/backup_restore